# underscore keyCode conversion issue with keyDown in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ascii, barcode, keypress, keydown

I am logging a barcode being scanned, which is detected from a tilde `~` keyCode event. Each keyCode after the tilde is logged and converted to its fromCharCode() value and pushed into an array. I was using a keydown event to log characters:

```
 componentDidMount: ->
    $(document).on('keydown', @barCodeDetection)
```

The keydown logs everything, especially the tilde (`~`) which is what starts the rest of the function, but keyDown converts the keyCode differently for underscores (`_`).

keyDown: `_`  logs as keyCode **189** -> converts to `½` (breaks the barcode character conversion)

keyPress: `_` logs as keyCode **95** -> actually converts to `_` (desired output)

I am trying to figure out how I can either a) use the keyPress event to log keyCodes w/o any actual keypresses, b) keep keyDown as the event trigger and convert underscores `_` (or any ASCII char) as if it were a keyPress (as keyPress event converts keyCodes to the desired output), or c) use the keyDown event to trigger a keyPress event mounting and logging keys (i.e. register `~` via keyDown and then fire function registering keyPress events.

Function:

```
barCodeDetection: (e) ->
switch keyCode
  when 192
    return unless e.shiftKey
    @_tildeLogged = true
  when 13 # return
    return unless @_listening
    @_tildeLogged = null
    @applyBarcode("barcode", @_barcode.join("")) if @_barcode.length isnt 0
  else
    return unless @_tildeLogged
    @_barcode.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) unless e.keyCode is 192)
```

Summary: keyDown logs an underscore as keyCode 189, I need keyCode 95, which is what a keyPress event would log, however this is a barcode scan and no actual keypresses are made. (Side question: does React as a virtual DOM have anything to do with keyPress events not registering "normally?")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is in React. This is how browser works.

Those events do handle events differently. `keypress` handles actual characters 'pressed' and that's why you have `charCode` field there. `keydown` handles keys. So, it will also handle SHIFT key press, for example. But it doesn't have any character associated (`charCode` is 0).

I think you go in the right direction to solve this.

[Good article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) and example at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this in the way mentioned in the question! 
@Andrey, indeed it isn't a React issue just stand browser behavior.

I implemented the keydown to trigger a keypress, so after a `~` is "heard", the keypress handles every keyCode after that - registering and converting characters such as underscores in the manner aligned with the desired outcome.

```
barcodeListener: (e) ->
  if #tilde event
    turn on KeyPress Event
  tilde var = true

barcodeFunction: (e) ->
switch e.which
  when # return
    tilde var cleared
    trigger other function i
    turn off listener
  else
    return unless tilde
    push converted keys to array
```